# Winform vb.net - how to change color of Tab?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, tabcontrol

How can I change the color of the Tab Page Header, the text that appears on the part of the Tab that is always visible?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the most elegant solution but.. Change the DrawMode of the TabControl to OwnerDrawFixed and handle the drawing yourself. Check [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.drawmode.aspx) for examples.

Comment: Too not elegant plus would require deal with all the other tabs and their text as well. All I want to do is change color of one tab's header.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to coding the DrawItem Event, followup with this event to change the tabpage text whenever you want to.

```
    Private Sub ChangeTabPageTextColor(ByVal TabPageIndex As Integer, ByVal ForeColor As Color)
    '  Get the area of the header of this TabPage
    Dim HeaderRect As Rectangle = TabControl1.GetTabRect(TabPageIndex)
    '  Identify which TabPage is currently selected
    Dim SelectedTab As TabPage = TabControl1.TabPages(TabPageIndex)
    '  Create a Brush to paint the Text
    Dim TextBrush As New SolidBrush(ForeColor)
    '  Declare the text alignment variable
    Dim sf As New StringFormat()
    '  Set the Horizontal Alignment of the Text
    sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center
    '  Set the Verticle Alignment of the Text
    sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Near
    ' Declare a Font
    Dim newfont As New Font(TabControl1.Font.Name, TabControl1.Font.Size, FontStyle.Regular)
    ' Draw the text
    TabControl1.CreateGraphics().DrawString(SelectedTab.Text, newfont, TextBrush, HeaderRect, sf)
    '  Job done - dispose of the Brush
    TextBrush.Dispose()
End Sub
```